# SCSS Breakpoints correction

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries, scss-lint

I have structured my breakpoints like this, i need 1024 break point. i already max-width 1199 getting conflict can some one please help me out with this.

// break-point
    // ------------------------------

```
/* Portrait phones and smaller */

@mixin bp-xsmall-only {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    @content;
  }
}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */

@mixin bp-small-and-below {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    @content;
  }
}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */

@mixin bp-medium-only {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    @content;
  }
}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */

@mixin bp-large-only {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    @content;
  }
}

/* Large desktops and laptops */

@mixin bp-large-and-above {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin bp-xlarge-only {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: What problems do you run into? If your goal is to target every different screen size individually, you will need many many more breakpoints.

Comment: One problem I see is that under some circumstances, widths are not always whole multiples of a pixel. I.E. the user can resize their window to be 991.5 pixels wide. So you should avoid that.

Comment: @MrLister i don't have any problem currently but in future i'm not sure with 1024px device can you please suggest me if you have any simplified one standardized breakpoints rather having bunch of this code.

Comment: What are you not sure about 1024px ? Why would it be a problem with 1024px precisely ?

Comment: @Durgesh You can test any window width you like by using a desktop computer and simply resizing the browser window.

Comment: @Alburkerk currently i have bunch of break points i need to minify more simple like for "mobile, tablet, large view" that's it. so if you have a level of quality or attainment break points could you please share.

Comment: @MrLister yes i did that.

Comment: @MrLister i modified and added latest code can you please have a look.

Comment: @MrLister I have structured my breakpoints like this, i need 1024 break point. i already max-width 1199 getting conflict can some one please help me out with this.

Comment: @Alburkerk I have structured my breakpoints like this, i need 1024 break point. i already max-width 1199 getting conflict can some one please help me out with this.